# Check if entry exists in other column and then classify as exists_in_both_col; exists_in_colA;exists_in_colB

Tags: sql, presto

- for each `merchant_id` **count** `product_id` that exist both in `store_a` and `store_b` which is then classified as a `'shared_product`
- for each `merchant_id` **count** `product_id` and find which `product_id` exist only in `store_a` or `store_b` respectively which is then classified as `'exclusive_product_storeA'` or `'exclusive_product_storeB'`

My query throws duplicated product_id's

**Table**

```
merchant_id   product_id    store_id    product_status
1             8328          store_a     new_product
2             9392          store_b     new_product
3             3828          store_b     old_product
1             8328          store_a     new_product
2             9392          store_b     new_product
3             3828          store_a     old_product
```

**Output table**

```
merchant_id    product_status   product_state              count_product
1              new_product      shared_products             2
3              new_product      exclusive_product_storeA    1
3              new_product      exclusive_product 1_storeB  2
2              old_product      shared_products             2
3              old_product      exclusive_product_storeA    1
1              old_product      exclusive_product 1_storeB  2
```

Comment: Why does your result set have only one merchant id?  Why is `store_id` in the result set?  That doesn't make sense, because `product_state` has that information.

Comment: apologies I just wanted to the different combinations for the output only for merchant_1

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . . if I understand correctly, you want two levels of aggregation, one at the product level and then summarizing that:

```
select merchant_id, product_status, product_state, count(*) as cnt
from (select merchant_id, product_id, product_status,
             (case when max(store_id) <> min(store_id) then 'shared'
                   when max(store_id) = 'store_a' then 'only store_a'
                   else 'only store_b'
              end) as product_state
      from t
      where store_id in ('store_a', 'store_b)
      group by merchant_id, product_id, product_status
     ) mp
group by merchant_id, product_status, product_state;
```

This doesn't include `store_id` in the result set -- it doesn't make sense because `product_state` has that information.

Comment: I get accurate results for 'only store_a' and 'only store_b' - but in cases where product_id exists in both stores it is not classified as 'shared' but instead to either 'store_a' or  'store_b'

Comment: @user12625679 . . . Can you set up a dbfiddle with appropriate sample data?

Comment: @user12625679 . . . I think I'm a bit lost on what you are trying to do.  Products have different types in different stores and different merchants.

Comment: You can think of the merchants as private sellers and the product_id as a product category. I would like to find out for each merchant how many products do they have in store_a exclusively, how many products exclusively in store_b and how many products are in store_a as well as store_b and this is split by product_status

Comment: I forgot to mention - there are only 2 merchants

Comment: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ijGdc1eVjjMVpY3HGy4xXg/3#&togetherjs=M9N90I4zfj